# Change client side scripts from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, build

I'm writing build process with node.js (using npm scripts). I want to change client side scripts from node.js. for example i have 3 files:

a.js:

```
(function () {
  function log() {
    console.log('log in a.js');
  }

  console.log('a.js');
})();
```

b.js:

```
(function () {
  function log() {
    console.log('log in b.js');
  }
})();
```

c.js:

```
(function () {
  function otherFunction() {}
})();
```

I want to run over the files and extend the `log` function (when exist), For example add another `console.log` at the end of the function.

How can i do it?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking. Do you want to go through your local machine's (or server's) file system, finding an updating these files? Or modify them on-the-fly when being served by Node (e.g., when Node is the web server)? Or...?

Comment: Files over the machine, in the build process

Comment: What kind of build software are you using?

Comment: I'm writing the build process in node.js, i want to change client side scripts in the build process, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the server, you may send emit to client side (maybe using socket.io),catch the event from client side and according to the event add your script?

Comment: It's for build process, not for web API